# Dynamic accessing of the php list

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables in the database employee(Ename,id,manager_id) and manager(name,id).1 manager has multiple employees under him. 
The first line extracts all the employees under 1 manager  and creates a list of it. Now, I wish to extract the name of each employee name from the retrieved employee id. How do i access each element of the list? This is what i have tried and it throws errors

```
$emplyeeId=DB::table('employee')->where('manager_id', $givenManagerId)->lists('id');  
for ($i=0;$i<listCount;$i++)
{
    $Ename = DB::table('employee')->where('id', $emplyeeId($i))-> value('Ename');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/queries#retrieving-results) (and scroll down a little bit, you find a method named `pluck`. This will return an array with all the values of the given column.

In your case this would be:

```php
$names = DB::table('employee')->where('manager_id', $givenManagerId)->pluck('Ename');

// This will return the following array:
['Kevin', 'Tom', 'Tina', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel pluck method ,for example get just name from data

```
$names = DB::table('employee')->where('manager_id', $givenManagerId)->pluck('Ename');
```

Second method with array_filter

```
$names = DB::table('employee')->where('manager_id', $givenManagerId)->get()->toArray();


$justNames=array_filter($names, function ($ar) { return $ar['Ename']; });
```